# Can a timestamp be extracted from GUID generated using mongodb c# driver AscendingGuidGenerator?

Tags: c#

Function that generates timestamp based guid

```
public Guid GenerateId(
byte[] machineProcessId,
int increment)
{
   var tickCount = DateTime.UtcNow.Ticks;
   var a = (int)(tickCount >> 32);
   var b = (short)(tickCount >> 16);
   var c = (short)(tickCount);
   var d = new byte[8];
   Array.Copy(machineProcessId, d, 5);
   d[5] = (byte)(increment >> 16);
   d[6] = (byte)(increment >> 8);
   d[7] = (byte)(increment);
   var guid= new Guid(a, b, c, d);
   return guid;
}
```

Sample `GUID` based on above function: `08d855c4-987c-51df-70db-ff1d6c000001`

[Mongo-C#-Driver](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/14e046f23640ff9257c4edf53065b9a6768254d4/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/IdGenerators/AscendingGuidGenerator.cs#L107)

Comment: This is not an actual GUID (the comments make clear it's used for testing). Specifically, it doesn't include any version number, using these bits for other purposes instead. Can you extract a timestamp from this? Sure. It's a terrible idea, though. Most GUIDs don't include timestamps anymore, and basing your architecture around "GUIDs" that do, instead of just storing the timestamp explicitly to make clear that you need it, is asking for maintenance headaches.

Comment: @JeroenMostert It's actual GUID. The testing comment is for exposing that method as public but internally it's used to generate GUID [Actual function](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-csharp-driver/blob/14e046f23640ff9257c4edf53065b9a6768254d4/src/MongoDB.Bson/Serialization/IdGenerators/AscendingGuidGenerator.cs#L89).
Thanks for the suggestions, I am aware of the downsides. But currently looking at a way to deconstruct the GUID to get timestamp

Comment: Used for testing or not, it's not a GUID. Don't confuse the type being used to implement it (note not the return type), with the concept of a globally unique identifier. Also, to paraphrase @JeroenMostert, don't extract timestamps from these values whatever they are. It really is a terrible terrible idea

Comment: The format of GUIDs is [documented](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Uuid). The version (type) of the GUID should be in there -- it's not. This is a custom sequence of hopefully-unique bytes that are shaped like a GUID, but they do not follow any of the existing algorithms. As long as those never escape a particular MongoDB instance they're fine, but it would be bad to mix them up with other sources, or assume they will always have this format. As to how you extract the timestamp: use `.ToByteArray()` and reverse the bitwise operators. The code for this is a little annoying, though.

Comment: Actually reversing the bitwise operator is where I was struggling with and am even not sure if can be reversed to generate the timestamp :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments by the others, this is technically not a GUID. Meanwhile, you can redo the bitwise operator this way:

```
public static long GetTicks(Guid target)
{
    var parts = target.ToByteArray();
    var result = new byte[8];
    Array.Copy(parts, 0, result, 4, 2);
    Array.Copy(parts, 2, result, 6, 2);
    Array.Copy(parts, 4, result, 2, 2);
    Array.Copy(parts, 6, result, 0, 2);

    var ticks = BitConverter.ToInt64(result,0);
    return ticks;
}
```

And then get the `DateTime` by `new DateTime(ticks)`, the sample "guid" in your question get converted to "9/10/2020 20:03:33" which looks correct...

Comment: just a note that with .net core 2.2+ you can use `BitConverter.ToInt64(result)`, without `0` as the positionIndex..